# How to disable animations on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, settings, animation

iPhone has many miscellaneous  animations. For example, there is a “*maximize window*” animation whenever we open an app, and a “*minimise window*” animation whenever we close an app.

On Android, we can opt to disable animations via *Settings* → *Display* → *Animations* → *No animations*.

How do we turn off animations on iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of to do this is to use a jailbreak tweak called Springtomize. Apple will not allow you to do this natively since it affects the aesthetic quality of the device. That's just Apple!

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS7 there are a couple of options for reducing animations and other UI effects such as translucency:

`Settings > General < Accessibility > Increase Contrast: On/Off` and

`Settings > General < Accessibility > Reduce Motion: On/Off`

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem on my iPhone 5s.

When I checked my [Reduce Motion](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202655) setting, it was disabled. Which means there must be motion.

So I powered off my iPhone and powered on it again. After that everything was back to normal.